# Ping-Pong Node Smoothing

Tags: procedural

How could I smooth out the top and bottom parts of the triangles?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Tsybe! as @Markus has commented below.. I thought the only reason you put the _Greater Than_  branch in your Q was to illustrate the function.. not actually to get the wave pattern...  sorry.. so as he says .. replace the _Ping Pong_ in your tree with the clusters illustrated in my answer, and leave the rest as it is. That should work.

Comment: .. See Edit.. I've returned your (very neat and tidy! :D) .blend, with adjustments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At its simplest, you could use *Map Range* to map the function from a linear, to a smooth, version of itself:

[image]

For more control, you could, for example, map the *Ping Pong* into a 0-1 range, through an *RGB Curves* node, and back out to its original range, after tweaking the shape:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, both of your results look pretty good! I've tried to replicate your nodes but unfortunately, something went wrong in mine. Now it looks like a simple *Wave Texture* node,  and there are no triangles anymore. I updated the post with the blend file, if you could take a look at it I would appreciate it!

Comment: @Tsybe R. Betts only posted a change, not whole node setup - he alters your `x`, but you still need to pass it to *Math: Greater Than* node, along with `z` as *Threshold*.

Comment: Thanks, @Markus.. will explain on OP.. :)